# Reactive Mongo could not find reader when wrapping .getAs()

Tags: mongodb, scala, bson, reactivemongo

I'm trying to wrap the `.getAs[T](String)` method in the BSONDocument class of Reactive Mongo so I can give a path to a property, instead of just the name. Here's the code I came up with:

```
def getPropertyFromBSONWithTransform[T1, T2](transform: T1 => T2, doc: BSONDocument, path: List[String]): Option[T2] = {

def getPropertyFromBSON[T1](doc: Option[BSONDocument], path: List[String]): Option[T1] = doc match {
  case None => None
  case Some(d) => path match {
    case List() => error("Shouldnt be here")
    case s :: List() => d.getAs[T1](s)
    case x :: xs => getPropertyFromBSON[T1](d.getAs[BSONDocument](x), xs)
  }
}

val value = getPropertyFromBSON(Some(doc), path)

value match {
  case None => None
  case Some(x) => Some(transform(x))
}
```

}

However, now it complains about not having a reader. Exact error:

```
Error:(26, 40) could not find implicit value for parameter reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONReader[_ <: reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue, T1]
    case s :: List() => d.getAs[T1](s)
                                   ^
```

I know how to solve this for one type, but I want to keep the function generic so I don't have to make it for every type I need. Because I want to decouple the reader from the data as much as possible, I prefer not to make a class for it to read it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot to pass implicit reader to main method. This should be work.

```
def getPropertyFromBSONWithTransform[T1, T2](transform: T1 => T2, doc: BSONDocument, path: List[String])(implicit reader: BSONDocumentReader[T1]): Option[T2] = {

   def getPropertyFromBSON(doc: Option[BSONDocument], path: List[String]): Option[T1] = doc match {
     case None => None
     case Some(d) => path match {
       case List() => sys.error("Shouldnt be here")
       case s :: List() => d.getAs[T1](s)
       case x :: xs => getPropertyFromBSON(d.getAs[BSONDocument](x), xs)
     }
   }

   getPropertyFromBSON(Some(doc), path).map(transform)
}
```